# git init and git push inside an heroku app

Tags: python, git, heroku, discord.py

i have a discord bot for me and my friends' server we usually relax listening to music using groovy we decided to make an ultimate playlist so i wrote some code which on every message that gets sent in the server if it starts with "-p " (groovy's prefix) it removes -p and writes the rest in a txt file,

code if anyone is interested:

```
@client.event      
async def on_message(message):

    to_process = message

    
    if message.content.startswith("-p "):
        
        message = message.content.replace("-p ", "")

        with open("index.txt", "r") as r:
            read = r.read()
            read = read + "\n"
        
        with open("index.txt", "w") as f:

            full_message = read + message 
            
            f.write(full_message)
            print("wrote {} to index.txt".format(full_message))
            
    await client.process_commands(to_process)
```

it works fine, all gets saved but obviously when i restart the bot on heroku the file gets resetted so i am wondering if i use git inside of heroku to git push the file on the bots' repository so that when i restart it, the file remains the same because it got pushed to github. technically yes, i tried dong so on my local machine but it didn't work because with os.system() or subprocess.call() cmd gets opened on the library's directory so how can i do it?, is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku has this file system called an ephemeral file system, where it discards written changes in your dyno, so that could be why your file is resetting. You may check about it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works#dyno-manager). If you don't want your file to be changed, you may have to add it to your git tracking and push it as well.